# Domain name change

Tags: domain-name-system, fqdn

I just ran into an issue with a client that we are migrating from their forest to a new forest using Quest tool Binary Tree

The issue is the source domain is called "domainname" and is not a FQDN "domainname.local or domain name.com"

It's the first time I've run into an MS forest that is not a FQDN and the migration tool requires a FQDN.

Anyone run across this before, any ideas how to fix or fake out dns ?

Thanks

Comment: since you did only post one small part of the issue, please provide also the rest.. Questions seeking installation, configuration or diagnostic help must include the desired end state, the specific problem or error, sufficient information about the configuration and environment to reproduce it, and attempted solutions. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers and are unlikely to get good answers.